# Representing variable-length 2d arrays in HDF5 format?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, hdf5

Looking through the HDF5 C API, I found `H5Tvlen_create` for creating 1d variable-length datatypes. How about multi-dimensional variable-length datatypes? Are they supported?

Clearly variable-length 1d datatypes can be combined to create 2d ones. However, is there a more direct way? My problem is that I have an array of structures (compound types), which have a property of type `int**` (or 2d int array). But, the size of the 2d arrays are not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to make this property of your compound array a [*reference*](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5R.html) to another dataset. You can put the referenced datasets in another group to keep things tidy, and of course each dataset can have its own size (or even a different number of dimensions).

<strike>Another ugly solution would be to have a variable-length array of variable-length arrays…</strike> Nah, don't do this!